# Test if 2nd column child in row exist [Python beautifulsoup bs4 tag]

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I built a scrapper for following site
https://web.acma.gov.au/rrl/assignment_search.lookup?pEFL_ID=5227509

and the green row header occurs randomly for different pages.

[image]

I am using remove function to just remove it from the list by filtering the row text so that both column are of equal size in my data set.

Is there a way i can test (if there's second column td in tr) in soup.select_one line of code???? so i don't have to use text based filters/rules that can be random.

Here is my code
github link = https://github.com/hassanharis/ACMA-Scrapper/blob/main/ACMAscrapper.ipynb

```
AntennaTableHeader = ['Licence Number', 'Device Registration ID', 'Client', 'Date Authorised', 'Device Type','Emission Center Frequency', 'Antenna', 'Antenna Height (AGL)', 'Antenna Polarisation','Antenna Azimuth', 'Antenna Tilt']
AntennaTable = pd.DataFrame(columns = AntennaTableHeader)

for acmalink in ACMAdata['links'][0]:
    url = 'https://web.acma.gov.au'+ acmalink
    # Create object page
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    Antennaheaders = [td.text for td in soup2.select_one('table',{"class": "tabledetail"}).select('td:nth-of-type(1)')]
    AntennaValues = [td.text.strip() for td in soup2.select_one('table',{"class": "tabledetail"}).select('td:nth-of-type(2)')]
    results = []
    if 'Registration and Application Details - 1' in Antennaheaders:
        Antennaheaders.remove('Registration and Application Details - 1')
    if 'Receiver Details' in Antennaheaders:
        Antennaheaders.remove('Receiver Details')
    if 'Registration and Application Details' in Antennaheaders:
        Antennaheaders.remove('Registration and Application Details')
    if 'Transmitter Details' in Antennaheaders:
        Antennaheaders.remove('Transmitter Details')
    if 'Device Details' in Antennaheaders:
        Antennaheaders.remove('Device Details')
    if 'Assignment and Application Details' in Antennaheaders:
        Antennaheaders.remove('Assignment and Application Details')
       



    AntennaDictionary = {Antennaheaders[i]: AntennaValues[i] for i in range(len(Antennaheaders))}
    AntennaTable_toAdd = pd.DataFrame([AntennaDictionary])
    AntennaTable = pd.concat([AntennaTable, AntennaTable_toAdd], ignore_index=True)
```

Expecting a better and flexible/dynamic way to select the row of table with random row headers on different webpages that i am scraping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem using comprehension list from python and documentation of beautiful soup

i can filter the random header rows using **colspan or class** as those tags are only present in header rows.

The solution is

```
if not td.has_attr('class')
```

In code

```
Antennaheaders = [td.text for td in soup2.select_one('table',{"class": "tabledetail"}).select('td:nth-of-type(1)') if not td.has_attr('class')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to go with `beautifulsoup`, you could exclude the rows with `colspan` attribute using [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
[
    dict(
        (e.td.text.strip(),e.td.find_next('td').text.strip()) 
        for e in soup.select('.tabledetail tr:has(:not(td[colspan]))')
    )
]
```

###### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://web.acma.gov.au/rrl/assignment_search.lookup?pEFL_ID=5227509'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

pd.DataFrame(
    [
        dict(
            (e.td.text.strip(),e.td.find_next('td').text.strip()) 
            for e in soup.select('.tabledetail tr:has(:not(td[colspan]))')
        )
    ]
)
```